# Get function arguments type as tuple

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

### Problem

> Given any function (or callable) type `Function`, how can I get its all arguments types as a tuple type ?

For example, I need a trait `function_traits<Function>::arguments`, where:

```
int f();
typename function_traits<decltype(f)>::arguments // => gives me std::tuple<>

void g(int);
typename function_traits<decltype(g)>::arguments // => gives me std::tuple<int>

void h(int, int);
typename function_traits<decltype(h)>::arguments // => gives me std::tuple<int, int>
```

### My thought

#### First

I need to get the size of arguments, fortunately boost already has implemented `function_traits<F>::arity`

#### Then

Generate an `std::integer_sequence` from 1 to artify, map it to arguments type, but here comes the problem, to map `integer_sequence`, I need something like this:

```
function_traits<F>::arg_type<N> // -> N-th arg_type
```

but boost only provides this:

```
function_traits<F>::argN_type
```

### Question

How can I implement `function_traits<F>::arg_type<N>` ? I can use c++ standard up to c++17

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename x_Function> class
function_traits;

// specialization for functions
template<typename x_Result, typename... x_Args> class
function_traits<x_Result (x_Args...)>
{
    public: using arguments = ::std::tuple<x_Args...>;
};
```

usage example:

```
#include <type_traits>

int foo(int);

using foo_arguments = function_traits<decltype(foo)>::arguments;
static_assert(1 == ::std::tuple_size<foo_arguments>::value);
static_assert(::std::is_same_v<int, ::std::tuple_element<0, foo_arguments>::type>);
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/lBnNKm)

Comment: How it works ? All usage will reduce to the first type, which is not implemented at all, it will never reduce to the second one.

Comment: @ZangMingJie The template specialisation is an exact match and more specialised than the general template. That’s why usage with a function will reduce to the second type.

Comment: @ZangMingJie I've added usage example

Comment: is it possible to make it work with lambda ? or any callable, and functor ?

Comment: @ZangMingJie That would require figuring out arguments of `operator ()` member function. It can be not trivial if `operator ()` is overloaded

Comment: after adding member function reduce and this `template<typename Class> class function_traits<Class> : public function_traits<decltype(&Class::operator())> {};`, it kinda works with lambda w/o auto arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Is too late to play?

You can use C++17 so... what about using `std::function` deduction guides?

```
template <typename T>
struct function_traits
 {
   template <typename R, typename ... As>
   static std::tuple<As...> pro_args (std::function<R(As...)>);

   using arguments = decltype(pro_args(std::function{std::declval<T>()}));
 };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

int f ();
void g (int);
void h (int, int);

template <typename T>
struct function_traits
 {
   template <typename R, typename ... As>
   static std::tuple<As...> pro_args (std::function<R(As...)>);

   using arguments = decltype(pro_args(std::function{std::declval<T>()}));
 };

int main ()
 {
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::tuple<>,
                 function_traits<decltype(f)>::arguments>);

   static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::tuple<int>,
                 function_traits<decltype(g)>::arguments>);

   static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::tuple<int, int>,
                 function_traits<decltype(h)>::arguments>);
 }
```

Comment: std::function requires copyable, and not all callable is copyable

Comment: Just tied this example without success https://rextester.com/EUHA75064  (c++17 is on)

Comment: @Dewfy - It's a problem of clang C++17 support: until clang 9 gives error, starting from clang 10 compile without problem.